# Using iText7 (C#), is there a way to modify the value in a field to include an href (Link to a website)?

Tags: itext, adobe, href, xfa

I am working on a prototype using iText7 for C#.  The PDF I am using is an XFAForm PDF and was created in Adobe Live Cycle Designer.  From my research, XFAForms do not support annotations.  I was going to add an annotation to the field with a link.

I want to be able to edit the value in a field to include a URL.  For example,

Name : Marc
should be:
Name : Marc https://www.google.com

I am able to modify the value in this field, but no luck adding a URL that is clickable.  I have tried the following:

1. `element.Add(new XAttribute("href", injectedURL));`  element is an XElement
2. Injecting HTML as the new value with a link

I was thinking about reading the XML, parsing it and injecting the URL in the XML and then writing it back to the PDF, but I do not feel that is a good solution.

Has anyone been able to do this?

Comment: I've added [tag:adobe] and [tag:xfa]. Before implementing this using iText, one needs to know what to implement...

Comment: Hey, a sample of a PDF and a more verbose description of what you are trying to achieve would be helpful